# ThreadDump:why thread state show different

Tags: java, jstack

```
"RVNUSDT-InstrumentAggregation" #168 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fba795e3000 nid=0x22be runnable [0x00007fb9c41c0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000005c1409df0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:550)
    at com.superatomfin.athena.feed.InstrumentAggregation.run(InstrumentAggregation.java:51)
```

first line show thread is runable,but second line show thread is waitting

why thread state is different

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct thread states.  The first line is showing the thread state for the (OS) native thread.  The second line is showing the Java `Thread` state.

These are different "state" values with different meanings.

Note that only the 2nd `Thread` state has a specified meaning from the respect of the Java specifications.  The javadocs for `Thread` say what `WAITING` means.

The first one is operating system dependent, and its meaning is operating system dependent.

Comment: Java Thread state is `WAITING` ,why OS Thread state is  `runnable`? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Why *should* they be the same?  They represent different things.   Clearly they aren't the same, and the simplest explanation for that is that they *do* mean different things!